# Is the variable in my propositional function bound or free?

Tags: logic

Quite a simple question but I think a good one, if I write

$P(n):$ some statement about $n$

is $n$ bound? Can I write that $P(n)$ is defined $\forall n$?

Comment: Please don't rely on the title of your MSE questions for important information. The body of the question should be self-contained. As things stand your question is far from clear. Can you give an example of a statement $P(n)$ that is troubling you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the variable $n$ is not bound but free in $P(n)$. You can bind it by placing it within the scope of a quantifer, such as $\forall$ or $\exists$, as follows:

$\forall n [P(n)]$, meaning "For every $n$, $P(n)$."

$\exists n [P(n)]$, meaning "There exists at least one $n$ such that $P(n)$."

Note you must also define a domain that $n$ ranges over, such as the set $\mathbb{N}$ of the natural numbers or the set $D$ of all donkeys.

As it is, $P(n)$ is a propositional function that does not actually make an assertion about anything and has no truth value. By specifying a domain and binding the variable, the propositional function $P(n)$ becomes a sentence with a definite true value, and it makes an assertion about one or more objects in the given domain.